# Web API deserialization is casting an int as a string, how can I prevent it?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have an API with a Post search action that accepts a body of json in the form of

```
{
    "EventID": [
        "1234-567-890",
        "1234-567-890",
        "1234-567-890"
    ],
    "boolFlag": 0
}
```

and deserializes that into a "SearchCriteria" object

```
    public class SearchCriteria
    {
        [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always), Required]
        public string[] EventID{ get; set; }


        [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always), Required]
        public bool boolFlag{ get; set; }    
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that if I input an eventID as the integer 1234, without quotes, that is technically valid JSON. And instead of making the ModelState invalid, by the time I get into my controller action, the value of that eventID goes from 1234 to "1234". And proceeds to be treated as a string throughout the rest of my code. We do not want users to be able to enter integers for eventIds. They must be strings.  Is there a way to attribute this property and/or prevent deserliazation from "casting" the int to a string?

Comment: since in your class you have defined it as a string array it will always be deserialized as a string

Comment: If `1234` is supposed to be invalid, then there are probably lots of invalid values. Validate your data when it comes in.

Comment: @MattBurland I am Trying to validate the data but I don't know which strings were originally passed in as integers and which ones should remain as strings. I'm trying to avoid checking if the string contains the "-" character

Comment: Why is that important? If it was originally a number, then it doesn't fit the pattern of your event ids and is invalid. If a number is valid, then you should probably treat it as a string anyway. Because if you have a data field that is sometimes a string and sometimes a number you are asking for all kinds of headaches. And unless you intend to do math with the event ids, you should probably just use strings anyway.

Comment: @MattBurland the EventIds are strings, and we store them in our database n the form of "1234-1234-1234". If the evenIDs the users enter are strings, we're fine with that, even if it's malformed. if they enter "abcdef" we will search for that and it will return 200 OK with 0 results, right? But if they give me a bunch of eventIDs and one of them is 11111. That's not even a string, and my manager is of the opinion that that is an invalid input. The problem i'm having is that serverside, that 11111 comes in as "11111", and is treated as a string and I'm not sure how to stop that cuz I'm a noob.

Comment: Then you might want to push back on that. If the valid format is `\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}` then check for that and return a proper error message if the event id doesn't fit that format. It's a horrible user experience to return 200 for a bad request. It's even worse if you sometimes *don't* send 200 for *some* bad requests because they fit *some* pattern that is somehow "more bad" than other invalid patterns that the user has no clue about.

Comment: So the only problem with the approach of checking if its in the valid format of \d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4} is that the EventIDs are an array of inputs, so if there's 499 valid ones and 1 invalid one, you either return an error message for the entire request, or, somehow store the information for the one faulty eventID that was not valid for the search so that we could let the consumer know...Or to my manager's point, you let them enter whatever they want, as long as its a string, and they only get results for the things that _exactly_ matched their eventIds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround: You can use the method [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert a string back to an int. Then you can do something like this:

```
public static void Main()
   {
      String[] values = { null, "160519", "9432.0", "16,667",
                          "   -322   ", "+4302", "(100);", "01FA", "11111", "1234", "1234-1234-1234" };
      foreach (var value in values) {
         int number;

         bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out number);
         if (result == true)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("This input value is definitely not valid as it is a number.");         
         }
         else
         { 
            Console.WriteLine("Perhaps this can be a valid input value as it could not be parsed as integer.", 
                               value == null ? "<null>" : value);
         }
      }
   }
```

For the sample data I use I get the following output:

```
Perhaps this can be a valid input value as it could not be parsed as integer. // null
This input value is definitely not valid as it is a number. // "160519"
Perhaps this can be a valid input value as it could not be parsed as integer. // "9432.0"
Perhaps this can be a valid input value as it could not be parsed as integer. // "16,667"
This input value is definitely not valid as it is a number. // "   -322   "
This input value is definitely not valid as it is a number. // "+4302"
Perhaps this can be a valid input value as it could not be parsed as integer. // "(100);",
Perhaps this can be a valid input value as it could not be parsed as integer. // "01FA"
This input value is definitely not valid as it is a number. // "11111"
This input value is definitely not valid as it is a number. // "1234"
Perhaps this can be a valid input value as it could not be parsed as integer. // "1234-1234-1234"
```

For a demo please see [here](http://ideone.com/9As1fE).

Comment: So Are you saying, tryParse and if it successfully returns to an int then it is only an Integer character, and this us not valid? Hmm this might work...

Comment: The only problem I have with this is Unit Testing. For unit testing we create an instance of the object in the test class so I can't enter an integer into a string array obviously, and if I enter a string of "1234" which gets caught by the Int32.TryParse, the test fails unexpectedly!

Comment: @LogicaLInsanity I'm not sure I am following your comment. However, please see my update and let me know what you think.